# How to persist data in localStorage in Firefox and Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to persist data in the local storage, with `localStorage.setItem('key','value')` and `locaStorage.getItem('key')` but as soon as I close the browser everything is deleted, Local Storage is not supposed to be persistent ? :(

Thank you for your help :)

Ps. I use a html file with some javascript, do we need a web server or domain for persist ?

Comment: can you please upload a web page demonstrating the behavior to a web server and share the url? i could test it in my web browser and tell you whether the problem is present. if yes, i could look into it. if not, it would mean that it's a problem with your dev environment.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage

Comment: It's not a web server, it's just a html file into my computer

Comment: You can use localStorage for the same local file and keep get the localStorage values after restarting the browser.  I just pasted the contents of [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_localstorage2) into a new file and ran that in Chrome and FireFox.  I then closed the browser, restarted it, reloaded the file and the counter continued from where it left off.  The data MUST have been stored even though the location started with file:///

Answer (score 1):

When you open a webpage locally with the `file://` protocol the browser won't associate the next opening session with the last one. So it is not possible to use localstorage with local file persistently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Do you have documentation about this ? How to use localstorage with local file persistently, it's possible with a local web server ?

Comment: You have to follow rules of same domain policy. A local web server should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.stringify-ing your 'value', eg:

localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(value));

and

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key"));

when getting your values.